# Sorting an array based on one column, then based on a second column

Tags: numpy, sorting

I would like sort an array based on one column, then for all the columns values that are equal - sort them based on a second column. For example: suppose that I have the array:

```
a = np.array([[0,1,1],[0,3,1],[1,7,2],[0,2,1]])
```

I can sort it by column 0 using:

```
sorted_array = a[np.argsort(a[:, 0])]
```

however, I want rows that have similar values at the [0] column to be sorted by the [1] column, so my result would look like:

```
desired_result = np.array([[0,1,1],[0,2,1],[0,3,1],[1,7,2]])
```

What is the best way to achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort them as `tuple`, then convert back to numpy array:

```
out = np.array(sorted(map(tuple,a)))
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 3, 1],
       [1, 7, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You first sort the array in the secondary column, then you sort in the primary axis, making sure to use a stable sorting method.

```py
sorted_array = a[np.argsort(a[:, 1])]
sorted_array = sorted_array[np.argsort(sorted_array[:, 0], kind='stable')]
```

Or you can use [lexsort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html#numpy.lexsort)

```py
sorted_array = a[np.lexsort((a[:,1], a[:, 0])), :]
```